# Intentional view overlap in Layout

Tags: android

I have a simple LinearLayout with 3 TextViews. They double it's size on click, and move up and down nearby views. But i need these TextViews to overlap nearby views instead of moving them to free space. I've already tried using RelativeLayout - same result. FrameLayout is not supposed to group list of elements. So how can i achieve such overlapping?

Comment: Where is your effort of code?

Comment: I can't post code from my project, cause it's protected by corporate law(

Comment: Surely you could make a "similar" layout that isn't an exact copy of the project

Comment: Try using RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. To achieve view overlap i've used RelativeLayout with fixed height.